# Visual Studio Post Build "xcopy exited with error -1073740791"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xcopy

My project does an xcopy of some files in the pre build using the command below

> xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)\Library*" "$(SolutionDir)\TAOutputDLLSet\"

Its been working without any issue till today when suddenly it returns the following error

> The command "xcopy /y "D:\BNCC\R2.PROD\code\CRM\TA\TA.BuildSequencer\Library*" "D:\BNCC\R2.PROD\code\CRM\TA\TAOutputDLLSet\"" exited with code -1073740791.    TA.BuildSequencer

I checked the event log and got this

> cmd.exe 
>      10.0.10586.0 
>      5632d6b1 
>      ntdll.dll 
>      10.0.10586.0 
>      5632d9fc 
>      **c0000409** 
>      **0003ea37** 
>      200c 
>      01d18be48a6bcd06 
>      C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cmd.exe 
>      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 
>      e8f0a086-4eb3-4546-a69a-a5c60f233d4c

When I try to run the xcopy command from command prompt the error does not happen?

Anyone able to advise on this issue?

Comment: Not sure it helps, but -1073740791 / c0000409 means 'Stack Buffer Overrun'. Not sure how you are getting that with xcopy. I read over this but not sure it helps with your problem: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190108-00/?p=100655

Could there be a lot of files starting with 'Library' in the folder you are trying to copy? Or is it possible you have a really really really long file name in the Library folder?

Comment: Using IDA on xcopy it seems that the error code you got can originate in two ways: `__raise_securityfailure` which is called when the stack canary gets overwritten (unlikely) and by the UnhandledExceptionFilter. You should try to attach a debugger and see the exception content, as I can't replicate the issue myself.

Comment: 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/151686/34exited-with-code-107374170134-when-executing-a-c.html 2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280250/faulting-module-name-ntdlldll.html